# My ActionLink created from controller is not Working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to create link using @Html.ActionLink which is passed from controller to view using ViewBag. 
Here is my code in controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
     ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";

     **ViewBag.Link = "@Html.ActionLink(\"Click\", \"About\", \"Home\");";**

     return View();
}
```

In my view I am using like this

```
<h1>@ViewBag.Title.</h1>
<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
**@ViewBag.Link**
```

but my output is not coming as link instead it is coming as string (i.e., `@Html.ActionLink("Click", "About", "Home");)` as in the below picture

[image]

And I even tried using `@Html.Raw(@ViewBag.Link)` but it still coming same as in the above image.

Can any one please help me with this.

Comment: You are doing it in the wrong place. that syntax is to be done in the view not the controller.

Answer (score 1):

It's showing up as a string because it is a string, and the browser can't do anything with that server-side code.

Invoke the helper in the view as code, don't pass it to the view as a string.  Something like this:

```
<h1>@ViewBag.Title.</h1>
<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
@Html.ActionLink("Click", "About", "Home")
```

Passing it as a string only tells the view to emit that string to the output, which it is dutifully doing in your code.